# How can I protect a wp-content/uploads folder in IIS with web.config only for loggedin users?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I've to protect a Wordress upload folder (wp-content/upload) only for loggedin users.
In many other sites (on Apache) I always use this .htaccess rules that redirects all traffic to a router file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But how can I do this in IIS? I know there are tools like Ape that makes htaccess working in IIS, but how can I do this in IIS with only web.config? (no visible redirect, thus the url must always be the same)

Comment: try the gui ? https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules